# Java class without specified generic argument loses type information on its methods

Tags: java, generics

Let's jump straight to the example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {

    static class GenericClass<UNUSED> {
        private List<String> someList = List.of("Hello world!");

        public Optional<String> getElement() {
            return someList.stream().findFirst();
        }
    }

    public static void generalMethod(GenericClass instance) {
        instance.getElement().ifPresent(string -> {  // <-- type info is lost here
            // gives error because "string" variable is assumed to be Object
            System.out.println(string.substring(0, 5));
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GenericClass<String> instance = new GenericClass<>();
        generalMethod(instance);
    }
}
```

Here we have a class with an unused generic. It has one method with explicitly specified return type of `Optional<String>`. I'd expect this method to preserve the type information on return value so that in `generalMethod` I can use `substring` on returned String even when `instance` argument there has unspecified generic type.

Yet there is a compile error:

```
/Main.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
               System.out.println(string.substring(0, 5));
                                         ^
  symbol:   method substring(int,int)
  location: variable string of type Object
Note: /Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

**Question**: Why does the absence of generic type on class instance lead to type information loss even for methods with hardwritten return types?

Side note: the error is gone if I write my argument as `GenericClass<?>` or with any other generic type.

Java version: 11.0.4.

Comment: I'd have to guess a little (would need to refer to the spec again) but I'd say that a signature like `generalMethod(GenericClass instance)` basically tells the compiler not to worry about _any_ generic type information in that method body or at least related to `instance` so the hard coded type will be ignored as well (keyword would be "raw type").

Answer (score -1):

If you don't specify a type parameter, plain Objects will be returned and you will only see Object methods.  You would then have to cast them to the correct type.